# Bash, tar "cannot stat no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I'm trying to build a little backup script but I keep getting the following error:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /projects: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The folder /projects exists, but still no tar ball is created. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_files="/projects"

#destination of backup
dest="/"

#Create archive filename
day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tar.gz"

#Backup the files using tar
tar -czf $archive_file $backup_files

#Print end status message
echo
echo "Backup finished"
```

ls -ld /projects shows the following:

```
ls: cannot access /projects: No such file or directory
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Comment: Do you have `/projects` directory? Lying in your / (root)? I bet you don't have.

Comment: Yes, the /projects directory exists.

Comment: Add output of `ls -ld /projects` to your question.

Comment: And `ls -ld /projects` shows what?

Comment: ls: cannot access /projects: No such file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filepaths that start with a leading `/` on Linux and other related systems are located at the root directory. This means that `"/projects"` usually refers to a different directory than `"projects"`.

It looks like you probably are trying to access a subdirectory `/path/to/projects` from directory `/path/to` using the path `/projects`. This is incorrect -- if your working directory is `/path/to`, you need to access folder `projects` by changing `backup_files="/projects"` to `backup_files="./projects"` -- `"."` refers to the current working directory -- or simply `backup_files="projects"`.

So, while relative filepaths `"./projects"` and `"projects"` are usually equivalent, they are generally and functionally different from the fully qualified path `"/projects"`.